# Tried four different methods to convert long to wide but all result in errors

Tags: r

My data looks like this

newdata

| APPLICATION | USER | APPLICANT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25428X. | P991. | A1 |
| 25428X. | P929. | A2 |
| 26619L. | P929. | A1 |
| 26619L. | P991. | A2 |

This is what I am looking for

| APPLICATION | A1 | A2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25428X. | P991. | P929. |
| 26619L. | P929. | P991. |

I have tried the following but have faced issues with all of them:
First try

```
library(tidyr)
wide<-newdata %>% spread(USER, APPLICANT, -c(APPLICATION))
```

> Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination
> of keys

Keys are shared for 944218 rows:
71988, ...*

Second try

```
reshape (newdata, idvar="APPLICANT", timevar="APPLICATION", direction="wide")
```

*This code just does not load*

Third try

```
library(tidyr) 
newdata_wide<-spread(newdata, APPLICANT, USER)
```

> Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination
> of keys Keys are shared for 944410 rows: 71988, ...

Fourth try

```
pivot_wider(newdata, names_from="APPLICANT", values_from="USER", id_cols="APPLICATION")
```

> Warning message: values are not uniquely identified; output will
> contain list-cols

Answer (score 1):

```
# Your data
dat <- structure(list(APPLICATION = c("25428X.", "25428X.", "26619L.", 
"26619L."), USER = c("P991.", "P929.", "P929.", "P991."), APPLICANT = c("A1", 
"A2", "A1", "A2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))

# Transform to wider form
dat %>% pivot_wider(names_from = APPLICANT, values_from = USER)

# A tibble: 2 × 3
  APPLICATION A1    A2   
  <chr>       <chr> <chr>
1 25428X.     P991. P929.
2 26619L.     P929. P991.
```

In base R using `reshape`:

```
newdat <- reshape(dat, 
v.names = "USER", 
timevar = "APPLICANT", 
idvar ="APPLICATION",
 direction = "wide")

colnames(newdat)[2:3] <- c("A1", "A2")

newdat
  APPLICATION    A1    A2
1     25428X. P991. P929.
3     26619L. P929. P991.
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. However, the same warning message arises: values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols. use 'values_fn=list' to suppress this warning. use 'values_fn=length' to identify where the duplicates arise. use 'values_fn' = {summary_fun} to summarise duplicates.

Comment: Is it probably a version issue? I run the code in R 4.20 with no warning. I run the code again on https://rdrr.io/snippets/  which use R 4.0.3 again with no warning.